# Growth of the reciprocal gamma function in the critical strip

Tags: gamma-function, cv.complex-variables

I was wondering if there are any results that studied the growth of $\left|\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\right|$ where $0 < \Re(s) < 1$ and as $\Im(s) \to \infty$? Any pointers to any results, papers, references will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Gradshteyn-Ryzhik: Tables of integrals... 8.328.1, for fixed real $x$ and for $|y|\to\infty$ one has
$$
|\Gamma(x+iy)|\sim\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-\frac\pi 2|y|}|y|^{x-\frac12}.
$$

Comment: And in general, Stirling formula (asymptotic expansion) holds
as $|z|\to\infty$ uniformly with respect to $\arg z$ in every
angle of the form $|\arg z|<\pi-\epsilon,\; \epsilon>0$.